# mongodb - upsert causing E11000 duplicate key error

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The upsert statement below does not work and get:

```
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.emails index: _id_ dup key: { _id: "8hh58975fw" }
```

My goal is to edit an existing document ( or create if exists ) with the same `_id`
The code in api is:

```
await db.collection('emails')
.updateOne(
  {
  _id: userId,
  type: "profileCompletion",
  time: new Date(),
  },
  {
    $inc: { "count": 1},
  },
  {upsert: true},
)
```

But I coped it from this which works:

```
await db.collection('analytics')
.updateOne(
  {
  _id: getDateMonYear(new Date(), "mmddyyyy"),
  type: "Geo",
  },
  {
    $inc: { "count": 1},
  },
  {upsert: true},
)
```

Comment: Where does `userId` come from? Like how is it generated?

Comment: its passed from req.body. Its fetched from db from another collection. Is that relevant though? I should be able to upset any row no matter what the `_id` is set as (in this case its `userId` but I should be able to do that even if the _id is hard coded as `test` ?

Comment: Very relevant. Sounds like there is a concurrency issue. _id is uniquely indexed so the behavior you seem to be experiencing is described here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-with-unique-index

Comment: I disagree only because the second example is the same thing - `_id` is exactly the same for the subsequent documents but it works. `getDateMonYear(new Date(), "mmddyyyy")` results in an `_id` of `Oct232022` is uniquely indexed and it gets updated the whole day. Isnt the idea of upset the ability to update a document with an existing `_id`?

Comment: The problem is about concurrency. There must be two threads attempting to perform the upset with the same value "at the same time".  You will only experience this duplicate key exception under those circumstances as both operations fail to find the document and both attempt to insert it. You can get the second variant to fail given the right timing of two threads as well

Comment: Your comments were based on the docs which actually say upsert with same `_id` is possible. It would confuse people so please consider modifying them. I will post the solution below.

Comment: You are absolutely right that I should have said that concurrency _may_ be the problem. I've added an answer to clarify a whole bunch of things and to tie some threads together. Thanks for helping sort this out

Answer (score 2):

As [@Kal shared in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74176016/20042973), the main issue in this particular question was associated with the usage of `time: new Date()`. This answer is intended to help explore why that is the case, help clarify how concurrency *could* still be a concern with the adjusted `update` in that answer, and what a safer `update` operation may look like.

##### Upsert Modifications

When a new document is inserted as the result of an `upsert`, there are a few ways the new document gets constructed. This is currently documented [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#insert-a-new-document-if-no-match-exists--upsert-). Relevant to this situation is the "*Set*" behavior (due to the change being defined as `{ $inc: { "count": 1}, }`) which uses an update operator. The relevant paragraph:

> If no document matches the query criteria and the `<update>` parameter is a document with [update operator expressions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/#std-label-update-operators), then the operation creates a base document from the equality clauses in the `<query>` parameter and applies the expressions from the `<update>` parameter.

So given a (new) `userId` of `123`, an `upsert` executed on January 1st would query the collection looking for a document that matches the following:

```
  {
    _id: 123,
    time: ISODate("2022-01-01..."),
    type: 'profileCompletion'
  }
```

Finding none, the `upsert` behavior would trigger and the operation would insert a document similar to the following into the collection:

```
  {
    _id: 123,
    time: ISODate("2022-01-01..."),
    type: 'profileCompletion',
    count: 1
  }
```

Now we move on to the what happens on a subsequent execution of the operation.

##### Upsert Matching

Let's say that the same operation (with `userId` of `123` is executed a month later at the beginning of February. The collection would be searched for a document that matches the following:

```
  {
    _id: 123,
    time: ISODate("2022-02-01..."),
    type: 'profileCompletion'
  }
```

While a document with the given `_id` (and `type`) *does* exist, the overall document does not match due to the difference in `time`. Similar to before, this triggers the `upsert` behavior and the operation attempts to insert the following document:

```
  {
    _id: 123,
    time: ISODate("2022-02-01"),
    type: 'profileCompletion',
    count: 1
  }
```

This of course fails with the aforementioned duplicate key error due to the existing document that contains the `_id` value of `123`. Stated another way, one of the problems is the fact that the timestamp is different every time this operation is executed.

Therefore the change to remove `time: new Date()` from the `<query>` portion of the operation does two things at the same time:

1. It eliminates the `time` field from being present in the document that gets originally inserted.
2. It subsequently removes that component of the `<query>` when matching resulting in the existing document being updated as expected.

##### Concurrency

I was (obviously) incorrect when I claimed in the comments that the problem that you were experiencing *was* the result of concurrency. More correctly I should have stated that it *may* be the result of concurrency. This remains true after the change to remove `time` from the operation.

The documentation about upsert includes [the following note](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#insert-a-new-document-if-no-match-exists--upsert-):

> If multiple, identical upserts are issued at roughly the same time, it is possible for `update()` used with `upsert: true` to create duplicate documents.

It then links to another section that begins with:

> When using the
> `upsert: true` option with the `update()` method, and not using a unique index on the query field(s), multiple instances of a `update()` operation with similar query field(s) could result in duplicate documents being inserted in certain circumstances.

I originally pointed to that documentation as "proof" that concurrency can be an issue. I believe @Kal originally correctly pointed out that the following text at the end of the section implies that the second operation should `update` as expected (emphasis added):

> With this unique index in place, the multiple
> `update()` operations now exhibit the following behavior:
>
> - Exactly one `update()` operation will successfully insert a new document.
> - **All other `update()` operations will update the newly-inserted document, incrementing the score value.**

This was news to me! I went back in time and took a look at [how that section was worded for version 4.0](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/reference/method/db.collection.update/#use-unique-indexes) (emphasis added again):

> The remaining operations would either:
>
> - update the newly inserted document, or
> - **fail when they attempted to insert a duplicate.
>   If the operation fails because of a duplicate index key error, applications may retry the operation which will succeed as an update operation.**

That text changed for version `4.2`. After digging around a bit I was able to find [this improvement request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14322) titled "*Retry on predicate unique index violations of update + upsert -> insert when possible*". The Issue Description suggests that there were some improvements made to this behavior *in some situations* for `4.2`, more on this in the following section.

##### Alternative (Safer) Rewrite

The aforementioned improvement shows that the server can now transparently retry an `upsert` that encounters a duplicate key exception under certain conditions. There is a table in that ticket that lays out what those conditions are, but they look to me like the ones that would be the result of concurrency between writes as opposed to other causes of the error *including* the `time: new Date()` problem in this particular question.

In fact, we can see that even the modified operation in the other answer will *not* transparently retry if it encountered a duplicate key exception. If I understand correctly, the modified operation would now have a `<query`> of `{ _id: userId, type: "profileCompletion" }`. This falls under row 6 described in that table as `type` is not part of the unique index definition.

In any case, while the modified operation no longer generates the duplicate key exception without concurrency, you may still wish to rewrite the operation. You can absolutely still add a timestamp to the document when it is inserted, but it shouldn't be specified in the `<query>` portion of the operation. Rather, it should be expressed either via `$set` or `$setOnInsert` as part of the described change, depending on exactly what behavior you want when the operation performs an `update`

Something along these lines:

```
await db.collection('emails')
.updateOne(
  {
  _id: userId
  },
  {
    $setOnInsert: 
      {
        type: "profileCompletion",
        time: new Date()
      },
    $inc: { "count": 1},
  },
  {upsert: true},
)
```

It feels like the documentation is a bit misleading so I'll send some feedback on the site.

Comment: Good job with the detailed explanation. I am sure it will be useful for other.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to remove:

```
time: new Date(),
```

from the query:

```
await db.collection('emails')
.updateOne(
  {
  _id: userId,
  type: "profileCompletion",
  time: new Date(),
  },
  {
    $inc: { "count": 1},
  },
  {upsert: true},
)
```

That was indeed the difference between the working and non working queries in my question.

**Summary:**
Upsert with same _id is possible no matter what the _id is as long as there is a unique index. In my case, `_id` was being derived and was the same plus it was the unique index.

*The link posted by the user who commented above is valid but the comments about multi threads etc are not relevant for this question.*