# mongodb - Conditionally increment field(s) using upsert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to insert/update (upsert) a document.

In the code below, this line is syntactically incorrect but that is what I am trying to do:

```js
     $inc: { {type=="profileCompletion"?"profileCompletion":"matchNotification"}: 1},
```

If type (passed in req.body) is `profileCompletion`, I want document to be

```js
    {
        "_id": "0h4wpbgy7u",
        "date": "Oct242022",
        "profileCompletion": 1,
        "matchNotification": 0
    }
```

Here the the query I have now

```js
    await db.collection('emails')
 

       .updateOne(
          {
          _id: userId
          },
          {
            $setOnInsert: 
              {
                time: getDateMonYear(new Date()),
              },
            $inc: { {type=="profileCompletion"?"profileCompletion":"matchNotification"}: 1},
          },
          {upsert: true},
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build the update object before passing it to the query:

```js
const update = { $setOnInsert: { time: getDateMonYear(new Date()) }};

if (type === 'profileCompletion') {
  update.$inc = { profileCompletion: 1 }; 
} else {
  update.$inc = { matchNotification: 1 }; 
}

...

await db.collection('emails').updateOne({ _id: userId }, update, { upsert: true });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in `MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection:` which I had resolved yesterday by adding time to setOnInsert - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74175751/mongodb-upsert-causing-e11000-duplicate-key-error