# mongoTemplate save results in DuplicateKeyException occasionally

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

When a record saved using mongoTemplate save method, occasionally it is throwing DuplicateKeyException. save method should internally use upsert and this should not happen under normal situations.  So far I cannot reproduce this in test environment but only on production occasionally. Current version used:

- MongoDB: 3.4.12
- mongodb-driver-sync: 4.6.0
- spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb: 2.7.0
- springboot: 2.7.0

```
org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: Write operation error on server mongodb1:27017. Write error: WriteError{code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: push-db.devices index: _id_ dup key: { : { platformId: 15, uuid: "eW9Zale3ST2EPPtFLQf3R5:APA91bGcXIc4ZIQZ3qVNTp1nDo981oPmj4CR5EXJspU-Ge_oQq1b12v0HLP7E-CPjF5qrK44K7Zr5Fszl0c6tGEmboKg2QrZoQpwFTAb6a_pICvX8V8ZJwbVIW1aMrC..." } }', details={}}.; 
nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Write operation error on server mongodb1:27017. Write error: WriteError{code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: push-db.devices index: _id_ dup key: { : { platformId: 15, uuid: "eW9Zale3ST2EPPtFLQf3R5:APA91bGcXIc4ZIQZ3qVNTp1nDo981oPmj4CR5EXJspU-Ge_oQq1b12v0HLP7E-CPjF5qrK44K7Zr5Fszl0c6tGEmboKg2QrZoQpwFTAb6a_pICvX8V8ZJwbVIW1aMrC..." } }', details={}}. at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:106) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:3044) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.execute(MongoTemplate.java:600) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.saveDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1595) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:1530) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:1473) at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.save(MongoTemplate.java:1458)
```

I can see index _id exists.

```json
   {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "push-db.devices"
    },
```

In mongodb collection, data look like this. id consists of platformId and uuid:

```json
{
    "_id" : {
        "platformId" : 15,
        "uuid" : "eW9Zale3ST2EPPtFLQf3R5:APA91bGcXIc4ZIQZ3qVNTp1nDo981oPmj4CR5EXJspU-Ge_oQq1b12v0HLP7E-CPjF5qrK44K7Zr5Fszl0c6tGEmboKg2QrZoQpwFTAb6a_pICvX8V8ZJwbVIW1aMrCasq2323232"
    },
    "appId" : 32342,
    "appVersion" : "33.556.66",
    "tags" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 39391,
            "lastLogin" : NumberLong(1666903871334),
            "loginCount" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 34269,
            "lastLogin" : NumberLong(1666903871526),
            "loginCount" : 1
        }
    ],
    "_class" : "com.myCompany.device.PushDevice"
}
```

Java snippet that saves data:

```
private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  @Override
  public void storeDevice(PushDevice device) {
      mongoTemplate.save(device);
  }
```

Mongodb runs as a replication set of 3 servers.

I tried updating driver to latest but did not helped. Any hints to the solution will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Prior to version `4.2`, duplicate key exceptions were an expected possibility when using `upsert` with concurrency. See the "Concurrency" section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74175751/mongodb-upsert-causing-e11000-duplicate-key-error/74176469#74176469)

Comment: Yes, there could be a case of concurrency but it says the concurrency issue can happen when index is not unique. I thought id field is unique by default: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-with-unique-index and https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/

Comment: The concurrency issue happens regardless of whether or not the index is unique. If the index is NOT unique, then you will get duplicate entries. If it IS unique, as the `_id` index is, then you will get the duplicate key exception. In version `4.2`, the duplicate key exception is automatically retried (under certain/most conditions).